# Can't boot freshly burned Ubuntu cd

Tags: macosx

So I just burned a Ubuntu 12.04.1 powerpc .iso on a cd for my iMac G5 running Mac OS X 10.4.11 and it won't even recognize the cd. I burned it on my dad's Windows 7 laptop as the process is way easier (just 2 clicks).

Mac OS X 10.4.11 gives me an error when it starts and when the CD is in saying "the disk you inserted was not readable by this computer". What's funny is that I burned a Ubuntu Minimal .iso on a CD and it would totally read that and even boot it though it gave me some errors afterwards and I couldn't install.

I even tried going into openfirmware and hitting boot cd:,\tbxi but I get the error "Warning sector size mismatch 
can't OPEN cd:,\tbxi
Can't open device or file"

Was there something wrong with the .iso I burned?

Mac OS X 10.4.11 won't even mount that .iso it tells me that the HFS file system is corrupt or something, but I know the .iso doesn't contain HFS file system.

Any help?

I downloaded the .iso from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso

Comment: Do and [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on the ISO file.

Comment: Oh wow, I just inserted the CD now and it doesn't give me that "not readable" error, I can actually browse the contents of the CD now. It must be that the CD drive is very old and is dirty inside, I've read a post somewhere that it needs thorough cleaning. I'll try swapping the optical drive from my dad's laptop into the iMac and report back if it works, I hope it does.

Comment: You might want to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally able to boot it with my dad's optical drive. It interestingly enough booted with my optical drive as well but it was so darn slow!!! For anybody wanting to change theirs it's super easy as the iMac G5 has a slim optical drive inside, just like a laptop one.